# Selector method of UIButton not called during animation

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

[image]I have dynamically created buttons on a dynamic view and later I add that dynamic view to main view.
Everything is working well except that the selector method of UIButton is not called.

```
var baseView:UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        randomizeButtons()}
    func randomizeButtons(){


        baseView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x + 10, view.bounds.origin.y + 50, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height-20))
        let viewWidth = baseView.bounds.size.width;
        let viewHeight = baseView.bounds.size.height;

        baseView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let  i = GlobalArrayofUsers.count
        var loopCount = 0
        while loopCount < i{

            let  userBaseView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(abs(CGFloat(arc4random()) % viewWidth - 90) , abs(CGFloat(arc4random()) % viewHeight - 120), 90, 90))
            print(userBaseView.frame)
            userBaseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            userBaseView.userInteractionEnabled = true

            userBaseView.layer.cornerRadius = 45
            userBaseView.clipsToBounds = true


            let button = UIButton(frame: userBaseView.bounds)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTapEventofBtn(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            button.setTitle("hello", forState: .Normal)
            button.userInteractionEnabled = true
            userBaseView.addSubview(button)
            baseView.addSubview(userBaseView)
            print("button  frame is\(button.frame)")
            baseView.bringSubviewToFront(userBaseView)

            loopCount += 1

        }
    }
    baseView.subviews.forEach { (users) in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: [.Autoreverse,.Repeat], animations: {
    users.center.y += 10
    }, completion: nil)
    }
    view.insertSubview(baseView, atIndex: view.subviews.count)

}

func handleTapEventofBtn(sender: UIButton!) {
    // handling code
}
```

Any idea why my selector method is not called? It is due to animation. How can i handle it.

**SOLUTION: Allow userinteraction in UIAnimationOptions**

Comment: Have you tried by replacing self with yourcontrollername in button target ?

Comment: @Gottz Yes But same issue persists.

Comment: Your code works when I throw it in a viewController.  Can you update your question to show the entire code of your viewController?

Comment: Do your buttons highlight when pressed?

Comment: @vacawama nope they are not.

Comment: The code presented above works.  You are doing something else in your real code to cause the problem.

Comment: @vacawama It is due to the animation block. If i comment it, everything works fine

Comment: @NA000022 all i did was making it more readable. solving an issue should never be done through an edit of the question by someone else than OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to click an object that is being animated. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:):

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are
>   disabled for the entire application.)

But worry not, the solution is very easy, just call your animation with the option `.AllowUserInteraction`. For example (with your code):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: [.Autoreverse,.Repeat,.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
    users.center.y += 10
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please check my new code. If i use animation it  doesn't work

Comment: @NA000022 Your code would not work anymore since `baseView` is never initialized + users is unknown

Comment: It is initialed now. The problem was due to animation , since i haven't added userInteraction in UIViewAnimation options

Comment: @NA000022 I could reproduce it + problem solved (see my update)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

```
for _ in 0...5{
    // generate new view
    let userBaseView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(abs(CGFloat(arc4random()) % viewWidth - 90) , abs(CGFloat(arc4random()) % viewHeight - 120), 90, 90))
    userBaseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    // add button to view
    let button = UIButton(frame: userBaseView.bounds)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleTapEventofBtn(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("hello", forState: .Normal)
    userBaseView.addSubview(button)
}
self.view.addSubview(userBaseView)
```

All you need is to create userBaseView before cycle, then create buttons in cycle and add them to userBaseView, after that just add userBaseView to self.view or where you need to add it. In your example you create userBaseView in every iteration of the loop.

I think the problem could be here:

```
userBaseView.addSubview(button)
    // add new view containing button to self.view
    self.view.addSubview(userBaseView)
}

userBaseView.addSubview(button)
baseView.addSubview(userBaseView)
```

First you add userBaseView to self.view in the loop:

```
// add new view containing button to self.view
self.view.addSubview(userBaseView)
```

then add it to baseView:

```
baseView.addSubview(userBaseView)
```

Can you post how it looks like in IB?

Comment: But I want the userBaseView to be dynamic as well.

Comment: I am doing it all programatically.

Comment: Ok, can you show the result on the screen? PS, Also pls check that your  userBaseView & baseView are userInteractionEnable = true

Comment: One more thing, have you got any gesture recognizers on the screen?

Comment: No there are not any gestures.

Comment: Also userInteraction is enabled as well

Comment: So probably the problem isn't here,  are you adding any other subviews to view? Can you post more code from this vc?

Comment: It is only due to animation block. If i comment it , it works

Answer (score 0):

// hi. your problem is in the selector line. try this:

```
for _ in 0...5 {
    // generate new view
    let  userBaseView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(abs(CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.view.frame.size.width - 90) , abs(CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.view.frame.size.height - 120), 90, 90))
    userBaseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    // add button to view
    let button = UIButton(frame: userBaseView.bounds)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true

    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    button.setTitle("hello", forState: .Normal)
    userBaseView.addSubview(button)
    self.view.addSubview(userBaseView)
}
```

// tested with xcode 7.2

```
func buttonAction() {
    print("working")
}
```

Comment: No selector method is ok. I have checked that.

Comment: is the method being called then?

Comment: No it is not being called anyway

Comment: using this also doesn't help?     :    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

Answer (score 0):

The action has a parameter so the selector signature is actually takeActionBtn:
(note the colon at the end).
You need to change that or the button will try to call a version of the function with no parameter which doesn't exist.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "button:",forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func button(sender: UIButton!) {
    // handling code
    print("1")
}
```